# How to get the body tag attributes for a specific element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to check if a specific element is present under the `body` tag I have stored at the beginning of execution.

I used below code and stored the attribute value in a String.

```python
Body_class= driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'). get_attribute('class')
```

Now I have to check if the 2nd element is present under the same Body_class.

```html
<body>
      <div>1st element</div>
      <div>2nd element</div>
</body>
```

Comment: _I have to check if a specific element is present under the body tag I have stored at the beginning of execution._ for me this sentence is not very much clear, can you please explain a little bit about it?

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal code

Comment: `.get_attribute('class')` could you explain this

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? (it's not very clear)

```py
any(
    [
        "2nd element" in element.text
        for element in driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").find_elements_by_css_selector("div")
    ]
)
```

This is the HTML file I used

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>1st element</div>
<div>2nd element</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are asking, but in case you wanna grab all class attribute value, under body tag then the below code can be used :

```
Body_class= driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
all_tags_with_class = Body_class.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class]")
for tag in all_tags_with_class:
  print(tag.get_attribute('class'))
```